# How do I use bluebird promises with request-extensible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, promise, bluebird

I want to use [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) to write a promise-based asynchronous web client. Currently I am doing this with the [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) package. At the top of my file I just put

```js
    var Promise = require("bluebird");
    var request = require('request-promise');
    Promise.promisifyAll(request);
```

and I'm good to go.

Now I want to add HTTP caching. Without bluebird, the way I know to do this is to use [request-extensible](https://github.com/suprememoocow/request-extensible).

```js
var requestExt = require('request-extensible');
var requestHttpCache = require('request-http-cache');
var httpRequestCache = new requestHttpCache({
  max: 1024 * 1024
});
var request = requestExt({
  extensions: [httpRequestCache.extension]
});
```

The request-extensible framework is asynchronous, but works via callback functions. I'd like to wrap it with bluebird so that I can use it with promises instead. How do I do that?

Comment: `requestExt` doesn't look like an asynchronous function. Why do you want to use Promises here?

Comment: You either use `request-promise` or you promisify, you don't need to do both.

Comment: @thefourtheye I clarified the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't `request-extensible` in a lot of detail, but it seems that the object it returns isn't necessarily compatible with "plain" `request` (it doesn't have any of the shortcut functions `.get()/.post()/...`, for instance).

So to wrap it by bluebird, it seems to me this is enough:

```
var Promise    = require('bluebird');
var requestExt = require('request-extensible');
var request    = Promise.promisify(requestExt({ ... }));

// Use like this:
request('URL').then(...).catch(...)

// Or this:
request({ OPTIONS }).then(...).catch(...)
```